# How to ng-style one element it's $index created by ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive, ng-style

- I have 2 directives: `wa-hotspots` & `wa-tooltips`.
- On `ng-mouseover` of `wa-hotspots` it takes that $index of `wa-hotspot` and sets the visibility and position of `wa-tooltip` via `ng-class:on` and `ng-style="tooltipCoords"`  by matching indexes.
- Note: Since `wa-hotspots` & `wa-tooltips` share the same collection `page.hotspots` and therefore they share teh same index via `ng-repeat`

**Problem:**
When you hover over `wa-hotspots` it sets the `ng-style` position to ALL of the elements in `wa-tooltips`.  I only want it ot set the proper matching index.  Since the visiblity is controlled by ng-class, This doesn't really matter but it seems like it's extra overhead that could be avoid.

Therefore:

**Question:**
How can I make sure that my ng-style isn't styling all the `wa-tooltips` on hover of `wa-hotspots`?  But rather, style only the tooltip that matches the proper shared index?

```
<ul id="wa-page-{{page.pageindex}}" class="wa-page-inner" ng-mouseleave="pageLeave()">


    <li wa-hotspots 
        <map name="wa-page-hotspot-{{page.pageindex}}">
            <area ng-repeat="hotspot in page.hotspots" 
                  class="page-hotspot" 
                  shape="{{hotspot.areashape}}" 
                  coords="{{hotspot.coordinatetag_scaled}}" 
                  ng-mouseover="showTooltip($index, hotspot.coordinatetag_scaled)" 
                  ng-mouseout="hideTooltip()">
        </map>
    </li>

    <li class="tooltip-wrapper">
        <ul class="tooltip">
            <li wa-tooltips 
                ng-repeat="hotspot in page.hotspots" 
                ng-class="{on: hovered.index == $index}" 
                ng-mouseover="hovered.active == true" 
                ng-mouseout="hovered.active == false" 
                ng-style="tooltipCoords" hotspot="hotspot">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**tooltip:**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make it per item like in your case - hotspot.tooltipCoords then set that variable by index. 
you can do the check inside the expression function.

Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/eTTZj/1121/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-style="isChecked($index)">
        name: {{item.name}}, {{item.title}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" /> 
   </div>
</div>
```

...

```
$scope.isChecked = function($index){
    var color = $scope.items[$index].checked ? 'red' : 'blue';
    return {color:color};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
ng-mouseover="hovered.active == true" 
ng-mouseout="hovered.active == false"
```

use

```
ng-mouseover="hotspot.class== 'active'" 
ng-mouseout="hotspot.class== ''"
```

and after that you can use hotspot.class in ng-class ie:

```
ng-class="hotspot.class"
```

Please see demo below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.items = [{
    id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3
  }, {
    id: 4
  }]

});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: yellow;
}
p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <p ng-repeat="i in items" ng-mouseover="i.class='red'" ng-class="i.class" ng-mouseout="i.class = ''">{{i.id}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So while this works the problem is applying ng-style not the class.  How can I make sure that only the mouseover affects the ng-style.  I'll be calculating the position of the bars therefore I need a conditional ng-style tag.  upvoted for effort!

Answer (score -2):

Use the below one

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="obj in items"> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm pull-right" ng-class="obj.class" ng-click="obj.class='test'" >
```

Write a new class "test". Instead of click you can use the same in `ngmouseover`